# Proving that the 'finite complement topology' is in fact a topology

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I am trying to rigorously work out the details of what Munkres calls the finite complement topology and, in particular, prove that it satisfies the axioms for a topology. There are a few details, e.g., taking a collection of nonempty sets, but the subcollection *itself* may be empty, that are a bit difficult to work out.

The precise statement of what I am trying to prove:

> Let $X$ be a set, and $\mathcal{T}_f$ the collection of all subsets $U$ of $X$ such that $X - U$ either is finite or all of $X$. Then $\mathcal{T}_f$ is a topology on $X$, which we call the finite complement topology.

My attempt:

> We have $X - X = \emptyset$, which is finite, and $X - \emptyset = X$, which is all of $X$, so $\emptyset, X \in \mathcal{T}_f$. Let $\{U_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in I}$ be an indexed family of nonempty elements of $\mathcal{T}_f$. It suffices to consider a collection of nonempty sets, as the empty set, while open in $\mathcal{T}_f$, contributes nothing to their union. Furthermore, if one element of this family of sets were empty, then their intersection would be the empty set, which we know to be open. We first claim that $\bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in I} U_{\alpha} \in \mathcal{T}_f$. We have
> \begin{align*}
> X - \bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in I} U_{\alpha} = \bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in I} \left(X - U_{\alpha}\right)
> \end{align*}
> by DeMorgan's law. Let $E'$ be one such $U_{\alpha}$. (If there is no such $E'$, then any $x \in X$ vacuously satisfies membership in $\bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in I} (X - U_{\alpha})$, so $\bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in I} (X - U_{\alpha}) = \emptyset$, which is open.) Then, since $E' \neq \emptyset$, $X - E' \neq X$, so $X - E'$ is finite since $E' \in \mathcal{T}_f$. But then $\bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in I} \left(X - U_{\alpha}\right) \subset X - E'$, and since any subset of a finite set is finite, we have $\bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in I} \left(X - U_{\alpha}\right)$ is finite, hence $X - \bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in I} U_{\alpha}$ is finite, so $\bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in I} U_{\alpha} \in \mathcal{T}_f$. Next, we claim that $\bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in I} U_{\alpha} \in \mathcal{T}_f$. We have
> \begin{align*}
> X - \bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in I} U_{\alpha} = \bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in I} (X - U_{\alpha}).
> \end{align*}
> For each $\alpha$, we have $U_{\alpha} \in \mathcal{T}_f$ and $U_{\alpha} \neq \emptyset$, so $X - \bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in I} (X - U_{\alpha})$ is a union of finite sets and therefore finite, so $X - \bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in I} U_{\alpha}$ is finite, so $\bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in I} U_{\alpha} \in \mathcal{T}_f$.

Am I correct that when Munkres says "any subcollection of open sets is open," this subcollection can be empty, even when we specify that the sets in the subcollection are nonempty?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on what you actually want to know. From what you have tried, the phrase 'if there is no such $E^{\prime}$' makes no sense. In order to prove that a given collection of subsets is a topology, one condition is that you need to show that any arbitrary union of subsets from that collection is again in that collection. You are explaining a situation where you are not at all considering any subsets for union. We are not interested in such a case.

Comment: It's possible I'm misunderstanding the axiom. The union axion says that any subcollection of elements of $\mathcal{T}$ should be open, but we could, in theory, have an "empty" subcollection -- or is that not allowed, because I haven't actually chosen any elements of $\mathcal{T}$? I'm viewing subcollection in the same way as subset, so I'm assuming we can have an empty collection in the same way as an empty set.

Comment: Any sub collection of Topology is not open. 'Open' set is an element of Topology. Open set is a subset of $X$, it is not a subset of Topology

Comment: an empty  subcollection has union $\emptyset$, check the definition of union. So we don't have to check it separately.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma This makes sense for unions, but isn't the intersection of sets in an empty collection the entire space?

Comment: @JeremyS that’s not always used but it’s a common convention. Is we don’t have to consider it separately anyway. Two is necessary and sufficient.

Comment: That makes sense, but my question then is, how do we know that's necessary and sufficient? Sorry, I'm just trying to understand the situation in full rigor.

Answer (score 1):

For unions you overcomplicate things: let $U_\alpha, \alpha \in I$ be a collection of open sets. We can assume WLOG that $I \neq \emptyset$ because otherwise the union would be empty anyway and we already know that $\emptyset \in \mathcal{T}_f$.

So $I \neq \emptyset$ and we can also assume that we have some $\alpha_0 \in I$ such that $U_{\alpha_0} \neq \emptyset$ or else all $U_\alpha$ are empty and so is the union, and we already checked $\emptyset \in \mathcal{T}_f$.

So $X-U_{\alpha_0} \neq X$ so $X-U_{\alpha_0}$ is finite. It's clear that $X-\bigcup_{\alpha \in I} U_\alpha \subseteq X-U_{\alpha_0}$ (if $x$ is not in the union, it's not in $U_{\alpha_0}$ in particular), and a subset of a finite set is finite, so $ \bigcup_{\alpha \in I} U_\alpha \in \mathcal{T}_f$.

---

For intersections you only have to check $U,V \in \mathcal{T}_f \to U \cap V \in \mathcal{T}_f$ and there we two trivial cases: $U=\emptyset$ and $V = \emptyset$ that we can rule out right away (then $U \cap V = \emptyset$ too) so $X-U, X-V$ are both finite and then $X-(U \cap V)= (X-U) \cup (X-V)$ is a union of two finite sets so finite and indeed $U \cap V \in \mathcal{T}_f$. QED.

---

In summary, once you've checked the empty set axiom, you can assume in checking the definition of a topology that in the union axiom we have a non-empty collection $U_i, i \in I$ of non-empty subsets and for the intersection axiom that we have two sets both of which are non-empty and not $X$. This can save you a litte case distinguishing in the proof.

Comment: I understand everything you wrote except for why we can rule out that the collection is non-empty in the case of intersections. I assume you began with two because induction will give us intersections for any $n$ sets; but how can we rule out that the collection is empty to start with?

Comment: @JeremyS the intersection of an empty subfamily (if you want to consider it at all) is $X$, already in the topology.

Comment: So we do not need to check it because it's trivial? (In other words, it isn't directly implied by the two-set case, but it's just not even worth checking.)

Comment: @JeremyS we already check $X$ separately. So we don’t need to do it again.

Comment: So is another way to read the axiom "any *nonempty* subcollection"?

Comment: @JeremyS the axioms are unions of all subfamilies and intersections of finite subfamilies. But in checking the we can reduce the number of cases.

Comment: But can we modify the axiom to say nonempty subfamilies? That's what confuses me. Because it seems that they are equivalent.

Comment: @JeremyS We make the axioms as simple as possible. We can prove the sufficiency of my reductions as a separate lemma of sorts.